# Inserting another character in place of spaces in Python

Tags: python, string

Lets say I have a String: `The Quick Brown Fox`. I want to insert a character in place of the spaces. So that it becomes:

`The-Quick-Brown-Fox`

I could do that manually by iterating throughout the string checking for spaces. But I was wondering if there's a elegant way of doing that by using some python built-in functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> 'The Quick Brown Fox'.replace(' ', '-')
'The-Quick-Brown-Fox'
```

Maybe you want to replace **any** whitespace, in which case:

```
>>> '-'.join('The   Quick  \nBrown\t Fox'.split())
'The-Quick-Brown-Fox'
```

or using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', '-', 'The   Quick  \nBrown\t Fox')
'The-Quick-Brown-Fox'
```